# How does Optimal Page Replacement algorithm works, when compared to Least recent used (LRU) page replacement algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, operating-system

Hi everyone I have read a text about page replacement algorithms and I want some clarifications, especially on the difference between the mentioned algorithms?

With regards !

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. Do you have some context for your question? Did you read a text about page replacement algorithms and want some clarifications? Do you want references to courses about page replacement algorithm? What kind of answers do you expect?

Comment: We're happy to share our knowledge and answer questions and help you, but with such a vague question, a stackoverflow answer most likely won't be better than what you can already find online, by searching for blog articles, university course (as written text or as slides), or on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_replacement_algorithm)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The "optimal page replacement algorithm" is not a real algorithm, or at least not one that can work in real time.

It's easy to understand, though:  You just swap out whichever page will not be needed for the longest amount of time.

You can't implement this as a real-time algorithm, because it needs to consider future events, and computers aren't psychic.  It's easy to implement if you know all the requests in advance, however.